# How can I append changing files to Tar archive with Apache Commons Compress

Tags: java, file, compression

I am creating a tar archive with Apache Commons Compress and keep running into the following exception:

> java.io.IOException: request to write '571' bytes exceeds size in header of '45536102' bytes for entry 'logfile.log'
>       at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveOutputStream.write(TarArchiveOutputStream.java:377) ~[commons-compress-1.9.jar:1.9]

The issue is that in the following code the file size actually changes from when I add the tar archive entry to when it reads it all into the tar output stream:

```
TarArchiveEntry entry = new TarArchiveEntry(fileToArchive);
tarOutputStream.putArchiveEntry(entry);
IOUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(fileToArchive), tarOutputStream);
```

How can I write the file into the tar archive if the file is actively being modified (it's a log file) while I'm writing it to the tarOutputStream?  Should I read the whole file into memory and then write it? or read only up to the size that the tar archive entry allows?  Those both seem like they risk data corruption.  The only other option I can think of is to copy the file on the local filesystem so it's not being modified and then compress that copy, but that seems kludgy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside tar archives the meta-data (including the size) is placed before the  actual content.  When using a non-searchable stream it is not possible to rewind and replace the size after it is known.

Apache Commons Compress only supports a pure streaming mode for tar so it is only possible to add entries if their content's size is the same as it was when the meta-data has been written.

You should look into ways to rotate the log before archiving it.